# Continuously combine lines of output of two concurrently running shell commands without using files

Tags: bash, shell, concurrency, sh

I have two commands that should run simultaneously. Both of them output a line of text when triggered by something. I want to continuously print output of these commands formatted into single line, when one of them outputs something.

For example if first command outputs (comments are not part of the output, just its order):

```
One   # 1
Two   # 5
Three # 6
```

And the second one outputs:

```
Aaa   # 2
Bbb   # 3
Ccc   # 4
Ddd   # 7
```

I want to get:

```
One -
One - Aaa
One - Bbb
One - Ccc
Two - Ccc
Three - Ccc
Three - Ddd
```

Basically, when any command outputs a line, I want to print this line with the last line outputted by another command, formatted.

I tried to do something like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

out1=''
out2=''

output() { printf "%s - %s\n" "$out1" "$out2"; }

command1 | while read -r out1; do output; done &
command2 | while read -r out2; do output; done &

wait
```

But it seems like parallel bash functions cannot access global variables, which makes sense now that I think about it. It'd be trivial to do by redirecting commands' output to files, but I don't want to constantly write data to disk. Is there a way to do something like this without using files?

P.S. Those programs are [i3status](https://i3wm.org/docs/i3status.html) and [akd](https://github.com/Shatur95/akd). I want to use `akd -p` option to constantly print current keyboard layout to stdout and combine it with usual i3status output to form a status line for [i3bar](https://i3wm.org/i3bar/).

Comment: So, you already have two (apparently related) event-driven programs, and want to write a third one in shell language instead of combining the first two - Doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Those programs are binaries and they're not written by me. Perhaps it's worth it to specify my real use case instead of abstract "commands". Guess I'll add it to the post.

Comment: first thought: create a named pipe, have `output()` read from said pipe, have the source commands write all output to the named pipe; possible issues: **a)** assumes the two commands (`i3status` and `akd`) have uniquely formatted output so that `output()` can tell where a line of data (read from the pipe) came from and **b)** (not 100% sure about this) could the 2 commands write to the pipe at the same time and end up overwriting/intermixing their output on a single line? ...

Comment: 2nd thought (address issues of the 1st brain fart) ... still going with the named pipe approach but with the following changes: **a)** each command (`i3status` and `akd`) feeds a `while` loop that adds a prefix to each line (eg, `i3status:<line-of-output>`, `akd:<line-of-output>`) before writing to the named pipe, **b)** before writing to the named pipe the `while` loop logic must obtain a lock on the named pipe (eg, `flock` ?) to ensure no collisions by the 2 processes writing at the same exact time; **c)** `output()` reads from the pipe, using the prefix to determine where the line came from

Comment: 3rd thought ... if for some reason `flock` doesn't work on named pipes, the `flock` could be applied to a separate 'lock' file (ie, once the writing process's `flock` succeeds on the 'lock' file, then write to the named pipe, then release the `flock` on the 'lock' file); see the comments/discussion to this [UNIX/SE question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/475267)

Comment: I think that the lines cannot intermix because `{ yes a... & yes b...; } | head -n 1000000 | grep -c -e 'a+b+' -e 'b+a+'` outputs 0 (`a...` = 36 'a' characters). And the output is distinguishable, because the first symbol of `i3status` output is always font-awesome's wifi character and it cannot appear in `akd -p` output. So I'll think what I can do with it, thanks for the idea @markp-fuso.

Comment: just fired up a linux VM and ran some tests; results of my tests: concurrent writes (by multiple processes) to the same named pipe can lead to data being lost 'in the pipe', so a locking method is needed to serialize writes to the named pipe; `flock`ing a named pipe appears to be buggy/non-supported (eg, my test scripts became unresponsive while eating up 100% of a single cpu), so I used a separate 'plain file' as a lock file (eg, `flock plain.file <do_some_action_that_writes_to_named_pipe>`)

Comment: @markp-fuso: I think that if the FIFO is kept open by some process or processes for both reading and writing, no data should be lost.  If you run multiple processes which open and close the FIFO, then data can be lost any time there is no reader or no writer.  IIRC, if a reader encounters EOF (no data, no writers), then nothing more can be read from that file descriptor.  If a writer writes when there is no reader, the write fails.  The process(es) with the FIFO open for reading and writing do not need to actually read or write; they just hold the FIFO open so that information is not lost.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler in my testing the writer hangs until a reader is started; for write testing I used a loop that writes (to the named pipe) on each pass ... which, in conjunction with the reader, was basically doing what you mention ... lots of opening/closing of the pipe); rewrote my tests so that the writers open the pipe once ... *tada* ... no lost data and (at least in my simple 'echo' tests) no overwriting/collisions of data lines going into the pipe (so no need for a lock, though I'd want to do more testing re: locking and concurrent writes to pipes)

Comment: @markp-fuso — that aligns with what I'd expect.  Writes to (anonymous) pipes and FIFOs are atomic as long as they're smaller than the buffer size — interleaving does not occur when the data written fits into the buffer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ... and due to the buffer-size/interleaving issue I'd probably err on the side of caution and use a locking mechanism, especially if I'm not sure of the volume of data coming through the pipe; anyhoo ... has been interesting test for my benefit ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

layout=''
i3status=''

{ i3status & akd -p
} | while read -r line
do
    if [[ $line == * ]]; then
        i3status=$line
    else
        layout=$line
    fi
    printf "%s | %s\n" "$layout" "$i3status"
done

pkill -P $$
```

There's a slight problem - i3status's output becomes uncolored, but that can be fixed with JSON output I think. Anyways - it's outside of the scope of this question. Thanks to @markp-fuso for suggestions.

P.S. Unprintable character inside square brackets is font-awesome's wifi symbol. It's always the first character of my i3status's output and that's how I distinguish lines. Another way would be using the length of the string - `akd -p` always prints two characters and `i3status` always prints more.